# CodeIgniter CronJob returning default view

Tags: php, codeigniter, cron

I'm having a really weird problem executing a CodeIgniter CronJob.

When i execute the task from the command line using "php /path_to_ci/index.php conjob" everything works as expected. But, when i add the same command to the crontab, the command returns the default view.

Does anyone knows what could be the cause of this?

I'm using CodeIgniter 2.2 and php 5.4, running on CentOS 6.6

Thank you for any help you can give me.

Comment: The first thing I would check is whether the cron task runs as the same user as when you run it from the command line personally. Things like privileges and environment can differ by user.

Comment: How can I check if the users are different?

Comment: have you tried with "full/path/to/php /path_to_ci/index.php conjob ?. I think that could also solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you @jagad89, the problem was solved by using "php5" instead of "php".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved when i used "php5" instead of "php".

So, the full command i used for the cronjob on the crontab was:

**php5** /path_to_ci/index.php conjob

Hope it helps anyone.